# Spy doesn't get called using async jasmine and requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, amd

I have a setup of AngularJS application that uses RequireJS to download and register services on-demand. I also use Jasmine for testing. I am trying to test if a function is called in the callback of a require() call that is executed inside of a module definition. Look at the following file I have and want to test:

```js
define(['app'], function(app) {

  app.registerService('myService', function($injector) {

    this.someMethod = function() {
      require(['some-other-file'], function() {

        var someOtherService = $injector.get('someOtherService');
        console.log("first");
        someOtherService.bla();
      });
    };

  });

});
```

I want to test that when myService.someMethod() is called, someOtherService.bla() is also called. This is my test file:

```js
define(['some-file', 'some-other-file'], function() {

  //....

  it('should test if someOtherService.bla() is called', function(done) {
    inject(function($rootScope, myService, someOtherService) {
      spyOn(someOtherService, 'bla');

      myService.someMethod();

      $rootScope.$digest();
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("second");
        done();
      }, 500);

      expect(someOtherService.bla).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

});
```

The console output shows that the statements are executed in the right order:
"first"
"second"

But the test fails, because the spy method never gets called. Why is that and how can I fix it? I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: did u create the spy for the someOtherService ?

var someOtherService = jasmine.createSpyObj('someOtherService', [ 'bla' ]);

Comment: Yes, that line: `spyOn(someOtherService, 'bla');`

Comment: I would not inject the someOtherService, but create a spyObject with the bla method, as mentioned above and then expect someOtherService.bla tohaveBeenCalled